# Get file names from a directory

Tags: c#, combobox, directory, system, getfiles

I tried the following using C#:

```
using System.IO;

string[] FileName = Directory.GetFiles("dir");
for (int i = 0; i < dir.Length; i++)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(Dirs[i]);
}
```

But for some reason it only gets 5 files from this folder. Is it possible to get all of the file's names and put them in the combobox?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't you want `i < FileName.Length` as your loop condition? And then `Add(FileName[i])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem :** You are getting all the FileNames into `FileName` string array but you are only getting 5 because you are not using `FileName` string array in your code.

**Solution :** You need to use `FileName` String Array instead of `dir`.

Try This:

```
string[] FileName = Directory.GetFiles("dir");
for (int i = 0; i < FileName.Length; i++)    
{
   comboBox1.Items.Add(FileName[i]);
}
```

**OR**

```
string [] FileNames = Directory.GetFiles("dir");
foreach (var filename in FileName)    
{
  comboBox1.Items.Add(filename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for this:

```
 string[] FileName = Directory.GetFiles("dir","*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(string fileName in Directory.GetFiles("dir", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(fileName)); 
}
```